# Unable to populate xib-created swift tableView using macOS

Tags: swift, macos

I am unable to populate a swift cell-based tableview in macOS 10.14.6 using an Xcode 11.2 xib.   The app is Document based and the tableView is created with a separate WindowController xib.  A similar project created programmatically in Xcode works ok, including drag and drop; I am relatively new to using xibs and likely have not set things correctly.  A column identifier has been set in the xib and NSTableViewDataSource and NSTableViewDelegate have been added to the Window Controller.  Pertinent source code follows and the complete Xcode project may be downloaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6tsb98b7iihhfxl/tableView.zip?dl=0

Any help in getting the tableView populated with a String array would be appreciated.  I would also like to get drag and drop working but can get by for now just getting the array items to show up in the table view.  It correctly creates four rows, corresponding to the number of elements in the array, but there is no visible text.  The tableView is cell-based, but I could use view-based if that would work better.  Thank you in advance.

```
class WindowController: NSWindowController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var tableView: NSTableView!

var sports : [String] = ["Basketball","Baseball","Football","Tennis"]

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        tableView.registerForDraggedTypes([NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.fileURL])
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return (sports.count)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
        var value : Any? = 0
        let columnIdentifier : String = (tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue)!
         if (columnIdentifier == "Col1"){
            value = sports[row]
        }
        return value
     }
```

Comment: From [AppKit Release Notes OS X 10.10](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/index.html): "Cell-based NSTableViews are now deprecated, and view-based NSTableViews should be used instead."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Document.swift `windowController` is released at the end of `showTableView()` and the table view looses its data source. Add `windowController` to the window controllers of the document or hold a strong reference to `windowController`.

```
@IBAction func showTableView(_ sender: Any) {
    let windowController = WindowController.init(windowNibName:NSNib.Name("WindowController"))
    addWindowController(windowController)
    windowController.showWindow(nil)
}
```